# Serverless Deploy From another Directory

Tags: amazon-web-services, serverless-framework, aws-codecommit, aws-codebuild

Here is my root folder and i want to deploy AWS Lambda functions to codecommit from the Backend folder.

[image]

Therefore i wrote this command, but AWS CodeBuild gives this error (This command can only be run in a Serverless service directory).

```
version: 0.1

phases:
    install:
        commands:
            - npm install -g serverless@1.20.2
    post_build:
        commands:
            - cd Backend
            - serverless deploy --region eu-west-1 --verbose
```

How can i deploy it from the backend folder?

Edit: I forgot to edit the version. Now i changed it to version: 0.2 and it works fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I forgot to edit the version of buildspec.yml. Now i changed it to version: 0.2 and it works fine.

```
version: 0.2

phases:
    install:
        commands:
            - npm install -g serverless@1.20.2
    post_build:
        commands:
            - cd Backend
            - serverless deploy --region eu-west-1 --verbose
```

Comment: don't you need to configure your aws credentials, does this just work?

Answer (score 0):

can you change to

```
 - cd Backend && serverless deploy --region eu-west-1 --verbose
```

Comment: When i changed the code, i forgot to adjust the version. But thanx.